# Friedman/Wilcoxon test. How to enter data for multiple repetitions?

Tags: spss, nonparametric, data-preprocessing

Id like to run a non parametric test such as the Friedman test on a dependent variable of my 8 subjects who have done a task under four different conditions.

I only found examples of how to input the data which had one value per condition for each subject: four vectors of 8 values (one for each subject) for each of the four conditions.

1 X X X X X X X X

2 X X X X X X X X

3 X X X X X X X X

4 X X X X X X X X

However my 8 subjects have done the task not once but 16 times under each of these four conditions.

How would I enter the data into the test such as in SPSS?

Can I just append the 16 values for each subject to these lists, creating four vectors of 8x16=128 values?
Or would I have to average the 16 values for each subjects beforehand to yield four vectors with 8 values each?

Thank you!

Comment: when you say "such as in SPSS" do you really mean "in SPSS" or do you mean (as it appears to ask) "in some statistics package, of which SPSS is an example"? Because if you mean what you seem to say, you'll probably get answer for how to do it in R.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I'm using SPSS so am answer regarding this software would be best. However I would ask like to know if it is valid to feed in repetition data as separate data points in friedmann in general.